# Python library not found in pyinstaller on Linux

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have python installed in Linux

```
$ which python
```

*/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/bin/python*

and also have pyinstaller

```
$ which pyinstaller
```

*/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/bin/pyinstaller*

Now I have created a sample python file **hello.py** in /home/username/test/ directory

```
 print "Hello World!!"
```

Using pyinstaller, when I am trying to create executable for it using below command then I am getting the **IOError: Python library not found: libpython2.7mu.so.1.0, libpython2.7.so.1.0, libpython2.7m.so.1.0**:

```
 $ pyinstaller hello.py

 532 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
 532 INFO: Python: 2.7.6
 534 INFO: Platform: Linux-2.6.18-371.el5-x86_64-with-redhat-5.10-Tikanga
 536 INFO: wrote /home/username/test/hello.spec
 591 INFO: UPX is not available.
 602 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
 ['/home/username/test', '/home/username/test']
 602 INFO: checking Analysis
 602 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
 603 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
 639 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
 757 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
 819 INFO: Caching module hooks...
 858 INFO: Analyzing /home/username/test/hello.py
 859 INFO: Loading module hooks...
 860 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
 6735 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
 6736 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
 6741 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
 7285 INFO: Looking for eggs
 7286 INFO: Python library not in binary depedencies. Doing additional      searching...
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/bin/pyinstaller", line 9, in <module>
 load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
 run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in 
 run_build
 PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", 
 line 788, in main
 build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), 
 kw.get('clean_build'))
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py",      
 line 734, in build
 exec(text, spec_namespace)
 File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-     
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", 
 line 212, in __init__
 self.__postinit__()
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", 
 line 161, in __postinit__
 self.assemble()
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", 
 line 543, in assemble
 self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
 File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/v2.7.6/lib/python2.7/site-
 packages/PyInstaller-3.2.1-py2.7.egg/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", 
 line 626, in _check_python_library
 raise IOError(msg)
 IOError: Python library not found: libpython2.7mu.so.1.0, 
 libpython2.7.so.1.0, libpython2.7m.so.1.0
 This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library 
 files.
 This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build 
 parameters of Python installation.

 * On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
 * apt-get install python3-dev
 * apt-get install python-dev
 * If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `-
 -enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
```

Please anyone tell me how to resolve this error and create a single executable using it.